# Jeep Rubicon sport 2007 3.7 won't go into gear

Tags: transmission, gears, clutch-plate

I need help please, my Jeep has a six speed manual geabox, but it does not go into gear. if you press the clutch it makes a noise, if you stop pressing the clutch the noise is gone, if you put it in gear you can hear it take all the gears but the clutch is not putting it into drive.

Comment: Do you intend to repair this at home?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information, then you need a new clutch assembly.

Comment: Agreed, I'd try bleeding the clutch hydraulics first in the hope it could be just low fluid in the system but it does sound likely that the clutch has failed and will need replacing.